# Printing integers in 32-bit fixed length binary

Tags: perl, string

I am using Perl to translate an integer provided by the user to binary form. For example, if the user input is "3735928559" (0xdeadbeef in hexadecimal representation), the program should output four chars respectively encoded in `\xde`, `\xad`, `\xbe`, `\xef`, instead of "deadbeef".

I don't want to use external modules, then how can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand right (you want the four bytes 0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, and 0xef), try the following:

```
print pack("N", $input);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your question isn't very clear, but I think you're looking for [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html):

```
my $input = '3735928559';
print pack('N', $input);
```